# Add custom information to an calender item in Office365

Tags: office365

We have integration of our own application with Office 365 Calendar. From our application we create calendar items that can be viewed from Outlook where extra information and action can be accessed via an Outlook Add-In. We want to add our own information to the calendar item that should not be visible to the end user to control the outlook add.

Is there a way to add our own data to a calendar item in Office 365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with OpenTypeExtensionModel. You can find more information at
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_post_opentypeextension

Example:
To create a extension on a calendar item you first need to make a class that contains the information and inherits from OpenTypeExtensionModel. In the next sample code I create a OpenTypeExtensionModel Abstract call, that my own class with data BookingExtention inherits from. I have an enum that contains the information (in this case I use calendar item as a booking and this defines the type of booking):

```
public abstract class OpenTypeExtensionModel
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.type")]
    public string Type { get { return "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension"; } }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ExtensionName { get; set; }
}

public enum ItemType
{
    Booking,
    Reservation,
    Option
}

public class BookingExtension : OpenTypeExtensionModel
{
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }

    public BookingExtension(string extensionName)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        ExtensionName = extensionName;
    }
}
```

Once you have these classes you can add it to an calendar item using the following code:

```
        private EventModel CreateOutlookEvent(string subject, string body)
    {
        Models.EmailAddress EventOrganizer = new Models.EmailAddress { address = "a@b.c", name = "Donald Trump" };
        Models.EmailAddress EventAttendee = new Models.EmailAddress { address = "x@y.z", name = "Hilary Clinton" };

        EventModel outlookEvent = new EventModel();
        outlookEvent.body = new EventBody { contentType = "Text", content = body };
        outlookEvent.subject = subject;
        outlookEvent.start = new Models.DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now
        };
        outlookEvent.end = new Models.DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        };
        outlookEvent.attendees = new List<Models.Attendee>();
        outlookEvent.attendees.Add(new Models.Attendee { emailAddress = EventAttendee });
        outlookEvent.isOrganizer = false;
        outlookEvent.organizer = new Organizer() { emailAddress = EventOrganizer };

        var extension = new BookingExtension("mindPark.Extensions.Booking")
        {
            ItemType = ItemType.Option
        };

        outlookEvent.extensions = new List<BookingExtension>();
        outlookEvent.extensions.Add(extension);
        return outlookEvent;
    }
```

And with this code you can create a event and post it O365

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEvent()
    {
        EventModel outlookEvent = CreateOutlookEvent("Debat", "Are you in for a debate?");
        await PostOutLookEvent(outlookEvent);

    }

    private async Task PostOutLookEvent(EventModel outlookEvent)
    {
        var accessToken = (string)Session["access_token"];
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "beta/me/events");
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outlookEvent), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```